# Service accounts permissions

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, service-accounts

I'm quite new to GCP. I have a service account with following roles:
[image]
I created a json key for it and used it to authenticate a gcloud client. This client is running on an instance on that project on that service account. I seem not to have permissions for anything:

```
# gcloud auth activate-service-account cloudbreak@**********-lab.iam.gserviceaccount.com --key-file **********-lab-804c90ab0a14.json
# gcloud auth list
                       Credentialed Accounts
ACTIVE  ACCOUNT
*       cloudbreak@**********-lab.iam.gserviceaccount.com
To set the active account, run:
    $ gcloud config set account `ACCOUNT`
# gcloud compute regions list
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.regions.list) Some requests did not succeed:
 - Required 'compute.regions.list' permission for 'projects/**********-lab'

# gcloud projects get-iam-policy **********-lab
ERROR: (gcloud.projects.get-iam-policy) User [cloudbreak@**********-lab.iam.gserviceaccount.com] does not
 have permission to access project [**********-lab:getIamPolicy] (or it may not exist): The caller does n
ot have permission
```

What am I missing?

Comment: This is weird because `Compute Instance Admin (v1)` and `Project IAM Admin` roles are sufficient to get permissions `compute.regions.list` and `resourcemanager.projects.getIamPolicy`. How do you authenticate with the service account? Do you start your compute VM directly with it (`gcloud compute instances create [...] --service-account=<your_service_account>`, or do you use the JSON key you have generated?

Comment: @norbjd, updated with authentication command. The machine I created with a deployment. I tried authenticating on the service account locally and I get same errors

Comment: Could you try (separately) : 1) to create a compute instance directly with the service account associated (`gcloud compute instances create [...] --service-account=<your_service_account>`) 2) to generate a new JSON key and try to authenticate (locally or from a compute VM) with it?

Comment: Did you try a `gcloud config set project PROJECTNAME` ? If you aren't in the project where the service account has got rights, you won't have any access ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by creating a new service account (with same roles) and using that one instead. I don't know what happens to the other one

Answer (score 3):

There is a long standing bug in GCP in which deleting a service account and recreating it with the same name can cause issues with its permissions not being recognised. The behaviour you describe (creating a new service account with the same permissions and seeing it work) matches the symptoms of this bug.

Answer (score 2):

To repair your service accounts you can follow the hints in https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-service-accounts.

The reason for the strange behavior is described as follows: `It is possible to delete a service account and then create a new service account with the same name. If you reuse the name of a deleted service account, it may result in unexpected behavior. [...] If you create a new service account with the same name as a recently deleted service account, the old bindings may still exist`

To remedy the issue:

1. Create the service account with the same name
2. Revoke all roles/permissions granted to that service account (will remove permissions from the *old* account)
3. Grant the needed permissions (will grant them on the *new* account)